# Cakephp3 ElasticSearch - How to get results

Tags: cakephp, elasticsearch, cakephp-3.0, elasticsearch-plugin

How do I get Data in Array format from a 'find('all')' call.

```
 $query->all ()->getResponse ()->getData ()['message']
```

gives me a json string '{\"_source[]....}'

Below is my code sample

```
    use Cake\ElasticSearch\TypeRegistry;
    class PagesController extends AppController {
        public function index() {
            $english_pages = TypeRegistry::get ( 'EnglishPages' );
            $query = $english_pages->find ( 'all' );
         // $query = $query->getData();
         // $query->all () ;
         // $query->all ()->getResponse ()  );
         // json_decode (  stripslashes($query->all ()->getResponse ()->getData ()['message']) , true ) ;
         // echo json_last_error_msg ();
         // json_encode ( $query->all ()->getResponse ()->getData ()['message'] ) ;
       }
     }
```

The Cakephp docs are not inline with the current Cakephp3 Elastic search on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same as using the ORM:

```
$query = $english_pages->find('all');
$results = $query->toArray();
```